# TypeORM ManyToMany relationship efficient query

Tags: postgresql, typescript, typeorm, typeorm-datamapper, typeorm-activerecord

```js
import { Entity, Column, BaseEntity, ManyToMany, JoinColumn, PrimaryColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Permission extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    code: string;
}

@Entity()
export class Role extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    code: string;

    @ManyToMany(() => Permission, { cascade: false })
    @JoinColumn()
    permission: Permission[];
}

@Entity('users')
export class User extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column({ unique: true })
    email: string;

    @ManyToMany(() => Role)
    @JoinColumn()
    roles: Role[];

    @ManyToMany(() => Permission)
    @JoinColumn()
    permissions: Permission[];
}
```

```js
hasPermission(user: User, code: string): Boolean => {
    // ...
}
```

I want to check efficiently if user has a permission or not.
i.e. John is a user with role `['inventoryManager']` and permissions `['listing:delete']`. And role `inventoryManager` has permissions `['listing:read', 'listing:update']`. So, `John.hasPermission('listing:update')` and `John.hasPermission('listing:delete')` both will return `true` while `John.hasPermission('listing:create')` should return `false`.

While I can select all and then loop over will be a solution but I that think as inefficient and over selecting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the QueryBuilder? https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md#getting-the-generated-query

You could then see the query output and try different join and filtering strategies and compare their efficiency.